# NSWindowController never deallocated

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have a `NSWindowController` subclass, and in the `windowWillClose:` notification I send autorelease to the window controller. But still dealloc is never called. I have no timers in the class, so that's not the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you call `release` instead?

Comment: same thing. `dealloc` is still never called.

Comment: I guess just look through your code and make sure you're not retaining another reference to it somewhere :-/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'm not. The only places in the class where I pass `self` to anything, is when using `NSThread` to perform a selector in the background. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Yeah it might... is the thread exiting before your window is closing? (either way, still might :-D)

Comment: Yeah, the thread is done before closing the window. Actually, `NSThread` is only used in certain functions of the window, and when those functions are not used the problem still occurs, so I guess it's not the problem...ugh

Comment: Hmm I can't think of anything else ATM... this *is* why I have grown to hate Objective-C though :-/

Comment: The easiest way to debug this is to override -retain in your subclass and set a breakpoint in it to see what's retaining it.  Bindings from nib objects to the window controller are automatically cleaned, so you don't need to worry about those. However, if you have an outlet from anything in your nib to the window controller, you need to make sure that it doesn't retain.

Comment: OK, just tried that. It's never retained. Instruments shows a retain count of 1 for the window controller whether it's opened or closed.

Comment: Then your problem is probably that you forgot to set your window controller as your window's delegate in your nib, so your -windowWillClose: method is never called.

Comment: Nope, it's getting called. Just tested it with an NSLog statement.

Comment: Instruments doesn't just let you look at the retain count; it also lets you look at everything that retained, autoreleased, and released the object. Do that, and look through the list of retains and their counterparts, and you'll find the one that isn't balanced out.

Comment: How do I see that stuff? Is it with the allocations tools?

Comment: Also, I've found that when I override retain and explicitly retain the class, my retain method still is not called. Could this have something to do with garbage collection?

Comment: OK, I figured out how to see release, retains, etc in Instruments. With GC enabled, my window controller is never released or retained. With GC disabled it is released and deallocated properly. Why is this? Should I not be using GC?

Comment: @edc1591: GC doesn't use retains or releases, and doesn't call `dealloc`. See the GC Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/ For GC, use the Object Graph instrument to see what (if anything) is keeping the NSWindowController alive.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I shouldn't be using GC then. I guess that's what I'll do since my app is mostly programed to work the non-GC way. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using garbage collection. I guess you shouldn't really use things when you're not 100% sure of how they work.